# Bootstrap Center Image and Right Align another Image

Tags: html, css

I have found parts and pieces to this question, but I can't get it right.

I am trying to center a logo image at the top of a page and then right align a second image around text that is below the logo image. I am not exactly sure how clear works as well. So far I have this:

```
.div1 {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.div2 {
float: right;
margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
clear: right;
}
```

then the images are set like:

```
<div class="div1"> <img src="images/angiervineyardslogo.jpg" width="200"         height="167" alt=""/></div>text goes here ...
<div class="div2"><img src="images/pink_ribbon.png" width="155" height="253"     alt=""/></div>
```

I want to create a responsive page, so I am using bootstrap, but I am way off track with all of this... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply the classes to your images and put all the styling in CSS, not in your HTML

```css
.centered {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<img class='centered' src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/105066/pexels-photo-105066-large.jpeg'>
```